# What species of Aloe is this?

Tags: aloe

Please help me to identify this Aloe species. Unfortunately I have dropped the container and that's why the plant lost a few leaves and therefore, its symmetry.
[image: What kind of Aloe]

Comment: I can't be sure from the picture, but does your plant grow its leaves in a circle/spiral or do they alternate opposite? If they alternate opposite (not in a circle or spiral), it's not Aloe vera/Aloe barbadensis.

Comment: I don't remember how the leaves were. Since then I gave it to somebody else and lost track of it. But thanks for the tip, it sure is useful for the next plants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly Aloe vera var. chinensis. There's a photo here: http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/272091/#b

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used your answer to search more on the web and I found on wikipedia that Aloe vera var. chinensis looks somewhat similar to Aloe massawana, which is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Aloe vera var. Chinensis is smaller leaved, and has white spots on the top of the leaves, and Aloe massawana has wider, and darker leaves, without spots.[image][image][image]